# Python request.get() response different to response in browser or when proxied over burp suite

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I am trying to send a get request with python like this:

```
import requests

url = "internal_url"  # I replaced all internal urls
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0", "Accept": "*/*", "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.5", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", "Connection": "close", "Referer": "internal url"}
r = requests.get(url , headers=header)
print(r.text)
```

As reponse I am expecting json data. But instead I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name) { // Local function for getting a cookie value
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start!=-1) {
        c_start=c_start + c_name.length + 1;
        c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);

        if (c_end==-1)
            c_end = document.cookie.length;

        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) { // Local function for setting a value of a cookie
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString()) + ";path=/";
}
function getHostUri() {
    var loc = document.location;
    return loc.toString();
}
setCookie('STRING redacted', IP-ADDRESS redacted, 10);
try {
    location.reload(false);
} catch (err1) {
    try {
        location.reload();
    } catch (err2) {
        location.href = getHostUri();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

When I changed the request to use the burp suite proxy so I can see the request, it suddenly works and I get the correct response:

```
proxies = {"http": "127.0.0.1:8080", "https": "http://127.0.0.1:8080"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False, proxies=proxies)
```

My browser displays the correct results as text when I visit the link itself. Burp suite proxy not needed.

I think its possible that it has to do with the company proxy.
But even when I tried to run the request with company proxies supplied it still does not work.
Is there something I am missing?

EDIT:
After some more searching it seems like I get redirected when I dont use any proxies in python. That doesnt happen when I go over the burp suite proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days and some outside help I finally found the solution. Posting it here for the future.

My problem was that I was using a `partially qualified domain name` instead of a `fully qualified domain name`

So for example: `myhost` instead of `myhost.example.com`

Burp suite or the browser were handling the translation for me but in python I had to do it myself.